# What would be a recommended data structure for a set of baking conversions?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am working on a Python package for converting baking recipes. Ideally, the recipe is simply stored as a CSV file read in by the package. Given the recipe can be imperial or metric units of measurement, I am trying to internally convert any set of measurement units to metric for simplicity.

The main question I am trying to solve is a light-weight way to store a lot of conversions and ratios given a variety of names that a measurement unit can be.

For example, if a recipe has `"tsp"`, I would want to classify it in the teaspoon family which would consist of `['tsp', 'tsps', 'teaspoon', 'teaspoons']` and have them all use the `TSP_TO_METRIC` conversion ratio.

Initially, I started as a list of lists but I feel like there may be a more elegant way to store and access these items. I was thinking a dictionary or some sort of JSON file to read in but unsure where the line is between needing an external file versus a long file of constants? I will continue to expand conversions as different ingredients are added so I am also looking for an easy way to scale.

Here is an example of the data conversions I am attempting to store. Then I use a series of `if-else` coupled with `any(unit in sublist for sublist in VOLUME_NAMES):` to check the lists of lists.

```
TSP_TO_METRIC = 5
TBSP_TO_METRIC = 15
OZ_TO_METRIC = 28.35
CUP_TO_METRIC = 8 * OZ_TO_METRIC
PINT_TO_METRIC = 2 * CUP_TO_METRIC
QUART_TO_METRIC = 4 * CUP_TO_METRIC
GALLON_TO_METRIC = 16 * CUP_TO_METRIC
LB_TO_METRIC = 16 * OZ_TO_METRIC
STICK_TO_METRIC = 8 * TBSP_TO_METRIC

TSP_NAMES = ['TSP', 'TSPS', 'TEASPOON', 'TEASPOONS']
TBSP_NAMES = ['TBSP', 'TBSPS', 'TABLESPOON', 'TABLESPOONS']
CUP_NAMES = ['CUP', 'CUPS']
LB_NAMES = ['LB', 'LBS', 'POUND', 'POUNDS']
OZ_NAMES = ['OZ', 'OUNCE', 'OUNCES']
BUTTER_NAMES = ['STICK', 'STICKS']
EGG_NAMES = ['CT', 'COUNT']
GALLON_NAMES = ['GAL', 'GALLON', 'GALLONS']

VOLUME_NAMES = [TSP_NAMES, TBSP_NAMES, CUP_NAMES, GALLON_NAMES]
WEIGHT_NAMES = [LB_NAMES, OZ_NAMES]
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is to help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Comment: Perhaps if you can show a [mcve] of your code not getting the right answers. Otherwise is sounds more like the start of a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: I'd use dictionaries: `standard_to_synonyms = {l[0]: l for l in VOLUME_NAMES}; synonyms_to_standard = {x: k for k,v in standard_to_synonyms.items() for x in v}`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I did not know about code review but that sounds like a better place. Thank you for letting me know!